Summarise into strings based on condition from other column
I'm struggling with a seemingly simple task: in df I want to summarise data in words into strings (no problem) and also the respective Durations of these words (problem). My attempt at subsetting Duration on the condition that [!is.na(words)] fails; instead all values in Duration get stringed together:
NB: I do not want to filter the dataframe on those rows only where words are not NA because in my actual data frame I have many more columns that I need to summarise in a similar way.
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  summarise(
    words = str_c(words[!is.na(words)], collapse = ","),
    words_dur = str_c(Duration[!is.na(words)], collapse = ",")
  )
            words                     words_dur
1 hey,how,are,you 44,150,30,55,77,80,99,100,200

The expected output is this:
            words      words_dur
1 hey,how,are,you    44,55,77,99

Data:
df <- data.frame(
  words = c("hey", NA, NA, "how", "are", NA, "you", NA, NA),
  Duration = c(44, 150, 30, 55, 77, 80, 99, 100, 200)
)


Does sapply(df[complete.cases(df), ], paste, collapse = ",") solve your task, or does it violate your NB? Cannot image how multiple summarise calls work together in one aggregated data frame.

As noted in an edit to the post I do not want to subset the data frame on complete cases as there are multiple other columns that also need to be summarised and where the NA values are in different rows

Then use df |> sapply(\(x) toString(na.omit(x))).

No, the result of this is: words                                Duration                     "hey, how, are, you" "44, 150, 30, 55, 77, 80, 99, 100, 200" 

When reversing the arguments to summarise, I get your expected result: df %>%     summarise(words_dur = str_c(Duration[!is.na(words)], collapse = ","), words = str_c(words[!is.na(words)], collapse = ","))

Alright, perhaps sapply(df, \(x) paste(x[complete.cases(df$words)], collapse = ",")) then. Or using is.na and toString to shorten code: sapply(df, \(x) toString(x[!is.na(df$words)]))

The problem here is that you have already re-defined words in the first calculation in summarise(). At this point words is "hey,how,are,you" so !is.na(words) is equal to TRUE which gets recycled and returns all values from Duration. Either change the name of the words variable in the first calculation, e.g. words2 = str_c(words[!is.na(words)], collapse = ",") or reverse the order of the calculations:
df %>%
  summarise(
    words_dur = str_c(Duration[!is.na(words)], collapse = ","),
    words = str_c(words[!is.na(words)], collapse = ",")
  )

#     words_dur           words
# 1 44,55,77,99 hey,how,are,you


You can try either or:
> df |> lapply(\(x) toString(x[!is.na(df$words)])) |> as.data.frame()
               words       Duration
1 hey, how, are, you 44, 55, 77, 99
> df |> lapply(\(x) list(x[!is.na(df$words)])) |> list2DF()
               words       Duration
1 hey, how, are, you 44, 55, 77, 99

